# Nginx dynamic load balancing

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

How do I have to create my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for using the REST-API? The Loadbalancing works fine, though. But creating an API endpoint does not function as I thought it should be.

When I try to start the service, it fails with this error message:

> `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "api" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:27`

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as too broad, unless you edit it and give us some more detail.  What does your config look like now?  What is on line 27?  What does `does not function as I thought it should` mean? What are you trying to do? I suggest you visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is resolved. Thanks!